# Ignite Performance: How to tune cache write performance for ignite thin client?

Tags: java, ignite

I am doing a simple POC to write a large volume of entries to ignite cache following client server mode, observed below during testing;

1)  If thin client and server reside on same host , it takes around ~10 minutes to persist 1 million entries into two cache.

2)  If thin client and server reside on different hosts , it takes around ~4 minutes to persist just 500 entries into two cache.This looks very bad.

I am not able to justify this significant delay in case2(mode we want to adopt for implementation) even if we take some network latency into account.I am wondering if its something to do with my cache configuration which is as below?

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <property name="workDirectory" value="/path/"/>

    <property name="activeOnStart" value="true"/>

    <property name="autoActivationEnabled" value="true"/>

    <property name="deploymentMode" value="SHARED"/>

    <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="test"/>

    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="storagePath" value="/path/"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!--
        For better performance set this property to false in case
        peer deployment is not used.
        Default value is true.
    -->
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>


    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <!--
            Specify list of cache configurations here. Any property from
            CacheConfiguration interface can be configured here.
            Note that absolutely all configuration properties are optional.
        -->
        <list>

            <bean parent="cache-template">
                <!-- Cache name is 'testcache1'. -->
                <property name="name" value="testcache1"/>
            </bean>

            <bean parent="cache-template">
                <!-- Cache name is 'testcache2'. -->
                <property name="name" value="testcache2"/>
            </bean>

        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- Template for all example cache configurations. -->
<bean id="cache-template" abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <!-- REPLICATED cache mode. -->
    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>

    <!-- Set synchronous rebalancing (default is asynchronous). -->
    <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC"/>

    <!-- Set to FULL_SYNC for examples, default is PRIMARY_SYNC. -->
    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>

    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
</bean>
```

Thin Client Code:

public class IgniteDataGridApplication {

```
static DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

private ClientCache<String, String> testcache1;
private ClientCache<String, String> testcache2;



public IgniteDataGridApplication() {
    ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("serverhostname.net:10800");
    IgniteClient ignite = Ignition.startClient(cfg);
    testcache1 = ignite.cache("testcache1");
    testcache2 = ignite.cache("testcache2");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IgniteDataGridApplication igniteDataGridApplication = new IgniteDataGridApplication();
    igniteDataGridApplication.load();
}

private void load() throws Exception {
    List<ThreadProducer> cacheMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        String testentry = i+"";
        cacheMessages.add(new ThreadProducer("testKey" + i, testentry));

    }
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
    cacheMessages.forEach(executorService::submit);
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}


class ThreadProducer implements Runnable {
    private String String;
    private String key;

    public ThreadProducer(String key, String String) {
        this.key = key;
        this.String = String;
    }

    public void run() {
        testcache1.putIfAbsent(key, String);
        testcache2.putIfAbsent(key, String);
        System.out.println("entry :: " + key + " :: " + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try profiling server nodes and the thin clients using JFR, JProfiler or another profiler of your choice to find a bottleneck that slows down the operation.

Make sure that in both cases the same number of nodes are present in the [baseline topology](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology). With improper configuration of the baseline topology data may be loaded only to one of the nodes.

You can try using API methods that load data in batches to improve the performance. [ClientCache#putAll()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.ignite/ignite-core/2.7.6/org/apache/ignite/client/ClientCache.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) is one of such methods.

Comment: Please also get to know the Performance Guide that covers persistence optimizations techniques and profiling mechanics: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/general-perf-tips